# Error Using Class Method Defined Outside of Class

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a class that I want to take an arbitrary method at initialization to use for string parsing depending on the context.

Using a method defined outside of a class as discussed here: [Python define method outside of class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455111/python-define-method-outside-of-class-definition)

```
def my_string_method(self):
    return self.var.strip()

class My_Class():
    def __init__(self, string_method):
        self.var = ' foo '
        self.string_method = string_method

    def use_string_method(self):
        return self.string_method()

instance = My_Class(string_method=my_string_method)
print instance.use_string_method()
```

I get the error "`TypeError: use_string_method() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`".

Shouldn't the `self` argument be passed implicitly to `use_string_method`?
Is there a way to define the function such that this occurs, or do I need to explicitly pass the self argument to methods defined outside of the class as such:

```
class My_Class():
    def __init__(self, string_method):
        self.var = ' foo '
        self.string_method = string_method

    def use_string_method(self):
        return self.string_method(self)
```

Comment: Ouch, that's tricky. I had something similar, can't find a workaround :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to wrap the passed in function in "MethodType".

From within your init:

```
self.string_method = types.MethodType(string_method, self)
```

This binds the method to the class and allows it to receive the implicit self parameter. Make sure you `import types` at the top of your script.

Comment: The other option is to wrap it in `functools.partial()` or a lambda that passes self for you.