# Call python method defined out of class within the class

Tags: python

```
import math

class Circle(object):    
    def __init__(this,x,y,rad):
        this.x=x
        this.y=y
        this.rad=rad

    def relate(circ1,circ2):
        diff=__posDiff((circ1.x,circ1.y),(circ2.x,circ2.y))
        print diff

def __posDiff(p1,p2):
    diff=math.sqrt((p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2)
    return diff
```

when I try to run the above code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Circle.py", line 18, in relate
    diff=__posDiff((circ1.x,circ1.y),(circ2.x,circ2.y))
NameError: global name '_Circle__posDiff' is not defined
```

Quite new to python, cant figure out how to call the function inside class.If anyone can help and explain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python define method outside of class definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455111/python-define-method-outside-of-class-definition)

Comment: @Basant: where does that post answer this specific problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename `__posDiff` to `_posDiff` (so remove one of the leading underscores).

You are using *double underscores* at the start of the name, and when using such a name within a class definition, Python *mangles* that name to produce a class-private name. This feature is used to add a namespace to methods that should not accidentally be overridden in subclasses.

This applies both to method names defined within the class, and *any code that tries to use such a name*. As such, your reference to `__posDiff` within the `relate` method is rewritten to `_Circle__posDiff` (the class name is prepended to create a namespace), but the `__posDiff` function itself is itself not re-named because it is not actually inside the class.

See the [*Reserved classes of identifiers* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) in the lexical analysis documentation:

> `__*`
>   Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form to help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and derived classes. See section [Identifiers (Names)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers).

And the linked [*Identifiers (Names)* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) in the expressions reference:

> **Private name mangling**: When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a *private name* of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named Ham will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`. ***This transformation is independent of the syntactical context in which the identifier is used.***

Bold italic emphasis is mine.

Comment: Thanks Martijn,this is really helpful