# Python: defining function outside class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to define a set of functions outside of a class that I want to use. Then however I want to make these functions available as methods inside the class.
Simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pylab

def my_plot(self):
    plt.clf()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(self.timeline, self.sample, color = self.color)
    plt.show()

class test(object):
    def __init__(self, color = 'black'):
        self.sample = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
        self.timeline = np.arange(1,101,1)
        self.color = color
        self.plot = my_plot
```

Now when I call,

```
my_test = test()
my_test.plot()
```

I get the error:

```
my_plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

However,

```
my_test.plot(my_test)
```

produces the expected result.

According to what I understand, `my_test.plot()` is equivalent to `plot(my_test)` so I do not understand why I should write `my_test.plot(my_test)` here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: More specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984352/4720935

Comment: thanks. Before I couldn't deduce from that question what I was doing wrong, but after inspecting it more carefully, I found what I needed.