# Define class functions in different source files?

Tags: python, class

Is it possible (preserving all the class functionality) to write the class functions in separate files?

Below is an example:

TestClass.py:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, param1=1, param2=2, param3=3):
        self.param1, self.param2, self.param3 =param1, param2, param3,

    def ClassFun1(self, param1=2):
        return param1**2/self.param2
```

TestClass2.py:

```
def ClassFun2(self, param1=3):
    return param1*3/self.param2
```

Next, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455111/python-define-method-outside-of-class-definition), I compile both files (I am too lazy to use import), create a class variable  and try to use `ClassFun2`:

```
x=MyClass()
x.myMethod=ClassFun2
x.myMethod(2)
```

As a result, I get an error, since `self` in `ClassFun2` is treated as a parameter, rather than class itself:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'param2'
```

Is it possible to split class definition into several source files? It is possible in C++ and this is actually very convenient when working as a team.

Comment: @RomanKonoval That's the question he linked to, so he obviously didn't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `x` is an object of the class, not the class itself. You need to do:

```
x = MyClass
x.myMethod = ClassFun2
```

Notice that I didn't put `()` after `MyClass`. That returns the class itself, it doesn't return an instance of the class.

Then you need to create an instance to execute the method:

```
y = MyClass()
y.myMethod(2)
```

Comment: Yeah, I did not understand/read to carefully that SO question I was referring to. That solves my problem. Thanks