# @tf.function( input_signature ) on an object's method defined outside of a class scope

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Say I have a `Custom Layer` :

```
class Custom_Layer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.w_0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform_initializer(),trainable=True)
        self.b_0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_initializer(),trainable=True)    
        ....
    def call(self, inputs):
        output = A_Method(self, inputs)
        return output
```

```
def A_Method(self, TensorA):
    ....
    return something
```

if I want to decorate `@tf.function(with input_signature)` to `A_Method` to control tracing

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[???,  tf.TensorSpec(shape=None)])
def A_Method(self, TensorA):
    ....
    return something
```

what spec should i put for `self` ? I tried putting `tf.TensorSpec` but it raised an error

`___Updated the question___ :`

Im quite new to tensorflow sorry if the code is weird or doesnt make sense. the reason I do this is I found RNN took a long time for first epoch to get started, I dont know if this custom layer can do something alike but is taking less time. but ultimately I believe the slow initialize time is because of tensorflow `retracing repeatedly even on same input_spec - input_shape`.
I use this layer repeatedly as,

```
input_layer = Input(shape=( X_.shape[1],X_.shape[2]),  name='input')
for loop :
Hard_Code_RNN_Layer(input_layer[:,:, slicing])
```

then I ran `.experimental_get_tracing_count()` count is 300
which really shouldn't be above 10, thats why I wanted to take this method out `def Mimic_RNN(self, step_input, step_state)` `remove it from the class` and try giving it an input_signature. Please see below :

```
def Initialize_Variable(input_dim, units):
    w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    w_0 = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units))) 
    b_0 = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(units)))
    return w_0, b_0
```

```
def Initialize_One_Variable(input_dim, units):
    w_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer()
    R_kernal = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units))) 
    return R_kernal
```

```
class Hard_Code_RNN_Layer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, input_tuple, Sequencee=True, **kwargs):
        super(Hard_Code_RNN_Layer, self).__init__()
        input_shape, units = input_tuple       
        self.Hidden_Size = (int)(input_shape * 0.85)
        self.inputshape = input_shape
        self.units = units
        self.thiseq = Sequencee
        self.Uz = Initialize_One_Variable(self.Hidden_Size, self.Hidden_Size)
        self.Ur = Initialize_One_Variable(self.Hidden_Size, self.Hidden_Size)
        self.w_hz, self.b_hz    = Initialize_Variable(self.units, self.Hidden_Size)
        self.w_out, self.b_out  = Initialize_Variable(self.Hidden_Size,self.units)
        self.w_0, self.b_0  = Initialize_Variable(self.inputshape,self.units)

    def get_config(self):
        cfg = super().get_config()
        return cfg 

    def Layer_Method(inputs, w_h, b_h):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, w_h) + b_h
    
    def Mimic_RNN(self, step_input, step_state):  <-----------input_signature_this
        x__j = self.Layer_Method(step_input, self.w_0, self.b_0)
        r = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(step_state, self.Ur))
        z = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(step_state, self.Uz))
        h__ = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x__j, self.w_hz) +  tf.multiply(r, step_state) + self.b_hz) 
        h = (1-z) * h__ + z * step_state
        output__ = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h, self.w_out) + self.b_out)
        
        return output__, h
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        unstack = tf.unstack(inputs, axis=1)
        out1, hiddd = self.Mimic_RNN(step_input=unstack[0], step_state=tf.zeros_like(unstack[0][:,0:self.Hidden_Size]))
        out2, hiddd = self.Mimic_RNN(step_input=unstack[1], step_state=hiddd)
        out3, hiddd = self.Mimic_RNN(step_input=unstack[2], step_state=hiddd)
        
        if(self.thiseq):
            return tf.stack([out1, out2, out3], axis =1 )  
        else:
            return out3
```

Comment: why is `A_method` using the `self` keyword while it's not in a class?

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply ! I read on tensorflow's website n it says ```If you need to force retracing, create a new Function. Separate Function objects are guaranteed not to share traces.``` I re-use this custom layer class multiple times so I moved ```A_Method``` outside from within the custom layer class, dont know if it makes sense. n I have to use ```self``` to pass the trainable variables to the method

Comment: Can you clarify if `A_method` is part of a class or not?

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your reply ! sorry that I didnt explain clearly, ```A_method``` is ```not``` a part of the class, it is just an individual def

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify an input signature, all inputs to the python function must be convertible to `Tensor`. `self` in that case, holds the reference to the instance on which the method is called on, and cannot be convertible as a Tensor. **You just can't specify an `input_signature` on your `A_method` function.**

However, it is still possible to decorate a method from a class, because TensorFlow will detect if the function to decorate is a method, and if that's the case, will automatically remove the `self` argument. You can check the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py#L2448-L2452):

```
if self._is_method:
  # Remove `self`: default arguments shouldn't be matched to it.
  # TODO(b/127938157): Should this error out if there is no arg to
  # be removed?
  args = fullargspec.args[1:]
```

It's worth noting that if a method is defined outside of the class, then this check will fail. (The check relies on the `ismethod` function from the standard library `inspect` module). As `self` is not convertible to a Tensor, the decorated method will throw an error when called.

It's not best practice to define a method outside of the class definition: it makes the code harder to read, and harder to use. You can give a look to that question for more details : [Define a method outside of class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455111/define-a-method-outside-of-class-definition). The python way of reusing logic between classes is either to use inheritance, or to define a function that does not depend on the attributes of the object (or where those attributes are passed as argument to the function).

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer, that surely's given me a better insight n understanding on input_signature. may I elaborate my situation further though, say ```A_method``` is used multiple times within the ```class``` then ```input_signature``` would only trace it once. however if I have multiple instances of the ```same class``` that I know have exactly same input_shape, how can I save some time to just let them know not to re-trace. I update my question a bit that should be clearer, may you please see again when free. Thank you very much

Comment: It's best to not update the question, but to ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You actually **can** use `input_signature` with class methods. The initial `self` parameter simply needs to be ignored in the input signature specification, so you just provide the `tf.TensorSpec` for the other parameters.

For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class MyClass:
    @tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec([None], tf.float32),
                                  tf.TensorSpec([None], tf.float32)))
    def my_method(self, a, b):
        return a + b

tf.print(MyClass().my_method([1, 2, 3], [4]))
# 5, 6, 7
```