# Code completion for defining a method outside of class definition?

Tags: python, class, methods, pycharm, code-completion

I want to use multiple methods outside of classes. How to define a method outside of a class definition is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455111/define-a-method-outside-of-class-definition).

It seems like a small afterthought, but the brackets for autocompletion and arguments disappear as a result, because it is seen as a field now. As I want to create a bulk of methods that are going to be used frequently, it would be nice to have it show the autocompletion and arguments again. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkq6s.png) is an example of what it's showing, I would like it to autocomplete with brackets and the respective arguments, as you can see with the `__dir__(self)` function. And here is the code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

def get_dap(self):
    pass

@dataclass
class Country:
    ctr_cc: str
    ctr_code: str
    ctr_name: str
    dap = get_dap

@dataclass
class Region(Country):
    reg_code: str
    reg_name: str
    dap = get_dap

dk1 = Region(ctr_cc="DK", ctr_code="DENMARK", ctr_name="Denmark", reg_code="DK1", reg_name="East Denmark")
dk1.get_dap()
```

I have tried to use some type hinting but I have yet to find a solution.

Comment: please paste code as text, thanks. you can use triple-backticks to make a code block

Comment: you should use a mixin class for what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Anentropic I was able to answer my own question ([screenshot with autocompletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWmwT.png)):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

class GetMixin:
    def get_dap(self):
        pass

@dataclass
class Country:
    ctr_cc: str
    ctr_code: str
    ctr_name: str


@dataclass
class Region(GetMixin, Country):
    reg_code: str
    reg_name: str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dk1 = Region(ctr_cc="DK",
                 ctr_code="DENMARK",
                 ctr_name="Denmark",
                 reg_code="DK1",
                 reg_name="East Denmark")
    dk1.get_dap()
```

Using a mixin and inheriting it in your preferred classes provides a better  method for reuse and allows for autocompletion.

Comment: Please accept this answer so that we would know that this question is solved. Thanks!